# Getting precise timestamps and differences in time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, time

What is the best way to get timestamps in iOS and then calculate time on e.g. 2 timestamps?

What data type is it? and if it is NSTimeInterval, can this value be stored in a dictionary that is then written to a plist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Unix time is best](http://unix4lyfe.org/time/). Indeed, using NSTimeInterval makes it really easy to calculate dates. It's just a double, so:

```
NSDate *startDate;
NSDate *endDate;
NSTimeInterval interval;
// assuming start and end dates have a value
interval = [endDate timeIntervalSince1970] - [startDate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

When the dictionary is to be serialised or written to a document database like Couch or Mongo, I usually record the time interval as a NSString:

```
NSDate *dateToStore;
// assume dateToStore has a value
NSTimeInterval aTimeInterval = [dateToStore timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *aStringObject = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%f", aTimeInterval];
NSDictionary *aDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:dateAsString
                                                  forKey:@"aKey"];
```

Then you can just read it back again when you use the dictionary object:

```
NSTimeInterval newTimeInterval = [[aDict valueForKey:"aKey"] doubleValue];
NSDate *retreivedDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:newTimeInterval];
```

If it's going to plist, you can just skip the string conversion.

Comment: why do you use NSTimeInterval as a pointer? I mean NSTimeInterval *

Comment: @ДенисПашков Thanks for the heads up - fixed!

Answer (score 2):

*NSTimeInterval* is a *typedef* of *double*. So you can add a time interval value to a dictionary as *NSNumber* by using,

```
NSNumber *ti_num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:aTimeInterval];
```

Comment: What about saving NSDate in the dictionary to be written to plist?

Comment: Yes. You can add a NSDate into a dictionary, and write into a plist.

Answer (score -2):

Just take a look at `NSDate` reference. All you need is there.

Comment: Answers that merely link to something are largely unhelpful. This answer doesn't even provide a link. This would be more appropriate as a comment.